# Emberjs Displaying and Creating a subclass to a model

Tags: ember.js, model, controller, subclass, each

Model: 'Category'
Subclass: 'Workflow'

I am trying to display the different 'Workflows' available for each 'Category' but I am receiving this error >>

```
Uncaught Error: Nothing handled the event 'createWorkflow'.
```

Here's some code

```
VpcYeoman.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    permittype: DS.attr('string'),
    isCompleted: DS.attr('boolean'),
    classNameBindings: ['isAdministrator']
});

VpcYeoman.Workflow = VpcYeoman.Category.extend({
    workflowtype: DS.attr('string')
})

VpcYeoman.Category.FIXTURES = [
  {
    id: 1,
    permittype:'Building'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    permittype:'Electrical'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    permittype:'Zoning'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    permittype:'Fire'
  }
];
```

I'm also a little stumped on how to make FIXTURES for this subclass. I attempted recreating VpcYeoman.Workflow.FIXTURES = [id & workflowType examples], but it didn't display.

Category.hbs

```
<div class="department-header">
  <div class="user-header">
    Category: {{permittype}}
  </div>
</div>
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
  <thead>
    <tr class="people-list">
      <td><h4>Workflow Type</h4></td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <table>
    {{#each workflows}}
      <tr>
        <td>
          {{workflowtype}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>

  <div class="input-bar">
      <img src="images/lightning-icon-edited.png" class="input-icon">
      {{input type="text" value=newWorkflowtype placeholder="Create a workflow and press enter" action="createWorkflow"}}
  </div>
```

&&

```
VpcYeoman.CategoriesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  actions: {
    createCategory: function () {
      var permittype = this.get('newPermittype');
      if (!permittype.trim()) {return;}

      var category = this.store.createRecord('category', {
        permittype: permittype
      });

      this.set('newPermittype', '');

      category.save();
    },
    createWorkflow: function () {
      var workflowtype = this.get('newWorkflowtype');
      if (!workflowtype.trim()) {return;}

      var workflow = this.store.createRecord('workflow', {
        workflowtype: workflowtype
      });

      this.set('newWorkflowtype', '');

      workflow.save();
    }
  }
});
```

&&

```
VpcYeoman.CategoriesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('category');
  },
  setupController:function(controller, model){
    this._super(controller, model);
    controller.set('workflows', this.store.find('workflow'));
  }
});

VpcYeoman.CategoryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you have a categories and category routes/templates based on the differently named things up there.

actions go the the particular route's controller `Category` then the route's route `Category` then up the routes `Categories`, `Application`

It looks like you are setting the workflows on the `Categories` controller, but trying to use it in the `Category` template